# How to experiment source code with `pdb`, `inspect`, `pprint`?

Tags: debugging, pdb

**Problem**

1. I want to understand source code of Kur (deep learning library)
2. I have no proper training in programming, I prefer to learn by experimenting without prior theoretical knowledge
3. I want an easy tool to help me dig into the detail workings of source code
4. debug tools are like `pdb` library seem to be a good choice to try
5. But what is the easiest way to get started in experimenting source with `pdb`?
6. I just want to write one line of code to dig into details, rather than writing a few lines as demonstrated in many examples when you google `pdb`

In other words, which function of `pdb` should I use? and How to use it effectively for experimenting source?

**Toy Example**

1. I want to explore the inner workings of `kur dump mnist.yml`
2. To make it simple, I want to just explore not beyond `__main__.py` and `kurfile.py`.
3. To be more specific, I want to explore `dump()` and `parse_kurfile()` in `__main__.py`, and `Kurfile.__init__()` in `kurfile.py`
4. Their relationship is as follows:

   console: `kur dump mnist.yml`  -->
   python: `__main__.py` :  `main()` --> `dump()` --> `parse_kurfile()` -->
   python: `kurfile.py` : `Kurfile` class --> `__init__()` ...
   python: ... the rest is not to be explored
5. Which function of `pdb` should I use to explore the execution flow from `dump()` to `parse_kurfile()` and to `Kurfile.__init__()` and back to `dump()` again?

---

**Update**

How to effectively explore Jupyter notebook using `pdb`?

- `pdb` inside Jupyter can't even remember console history, not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One possible solution**

1. use `pdb.set_trace` only
2. `set_trace` is trace the details on the level of the current code block, it will not go deeper to the next inner function.
3. for example, when I put a single `pdb.set_trace` inside `dump()`, `pdb` will not help me trace into the function of `parse_kurfile()`, but stay on the current `dump()` block:

   def dump(args):
       """ Dumps the Kurfile to stdout as a JSON blob.
       """
       pdb.set_trace()
       ### parse kurfile.yml into parts to be used in python code
       spec = parse_kurfile(args.kurfile, args.engine)
4. If I want to go deeper into `parse_kurfile` in `__main__.py` and `Kurfile.__init__` in `kurfile.py`, then I just need to put one `pdb.set_trace` in each of the two functions, like below:

[image]

---

**Update**

From my experience so far, there are two libraries `inspect` and `pprint` go well with `pdb` library.

Inside library `inspect`, I use the following functions the most:

1. `inspect.getdoc`: to see the doc of the function
2. `inspect.getmodule`: to find out where this function or object come from
3. `inspect.getfullargspec`: to find out all the inputs the func takes
4. `inpsect.getsourceliens`: to get the source code of the function

with these functions above, when I want to checkout other functions, I don't have to go to find the source code in editor, I can see them right where I am in the `pdb`.

From library `pprint`, you can guess, I use `pprint.pprint` to print out the source code, the doc in a more readable format right inside `pdb`.

---

**More Update**

A working station to explore and experiment source:

1. using `atom` to split window and see different source files at the same time;
2. use `iterm2` to split window and use  `ipython` to execute python or bash code
3. organise them in the following way:

[image]

---

**More update**

During exploring, I want to have all the attributes and methods of a module or class ready at hand.

To achieve it, I can use `inspect.getmembers(module or class name)` and use `iterm2` split window to view it:

[image]

---

**Update: How to change color of iterm2 for the eyes?**

Go to iterm2 `preferences`, `color`, change to `Tango Dark`, to gray the `foreground color` to make white texts look soft

Change Kur logger color setting to:

```
## logcolor.py
# Color codes for each log-level.
COLORS = {
    'DEBUG': BLUE,
    'INFO': MAGENTA,
    'WARNING': RED,
    'ERROR': RED,
    'CRITICAL': GREEN
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to effectively use `pdb` in Jupyter notebook?

One way to avoid the drawbacks of `pdb` in Jupyter:

- download the notebook into py file
- insert codes like `import pdb` and `pdb.set_trace()` into the python code
- in console, run `python your.py`
- Now you can explore this py file as you do in above answer